# Como sumar una columa o fila

Tags: java

tengo una duda de como puedo sumar solo una columna de una matriz bidimensional, será que me pueden dar una idea de como hacerlo gracias. este es mi código

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        int promedio , suma = 0 , sumaCol2 = 0, sumacol4 = 0;
        int m[][] = new int[12][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                m[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
            }
        }

                //sumar columna 2
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                
              // hacer la suma de la columna 2`introducir el código aquí`
            }
        }
        System.out.println("la suma columna 2 es : " + sumaCol2);
    }
}
```

solo tengo esa duda muchas gracias no me califiquen tan mal xd trato de aprender gracias

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente suma los valores de la segunda columna, indice 1 iterando sobre todas las filas, lo realizarìas de esta forma:

```
...
...
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      sumaCol2 += m[i][1]; //[filas][columna 2]      
}
...
...
```

Este serìa el còdigo:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   int promedio , suma = 0 , sumaCol2 = 0, sumacol4 = 0;
    int m[][] = new int[12][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            m[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
        }
    }
    
    //sumar columna 2
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
          sumaCol2 += m[i][1];
       
    }
    System.out.println("la suma columna 2 es : " + sumaCol2);
 }
}
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
   7    19     5    14 
   12    17     1    15 
    3     9    13    11 
   13     0    18     8 
   15    16     3     3 
    9    13    15    18 
   19    18     3    19 
   16     9    16     5 
    8    19     3     8 
    8    13    15     9 
    6    19    12     6 
   12    14    14     8 
la suma columna 2 es : 166
```